# How to add new row next to existing row having similar key in json

Tags: json

I have two variables having json data as below.

```js
var json1=
  [{  name: 'AAA', id: 100},
    {  name: 'BBB', id: 100 },
    {  name: 'CCC',  id: 101},
    {  name: 'DDD',  id: 102} ]
var json2=
 [ {  name: 'EEE',  id: 101}
    ]
```

I need get combination of both variables as below.

```js
var jsonCombined=
    [{  name: 'AAA', id: 100},
    {  name: 'BBB', id: 100 },
    {  name: 'CCC',  id: 101},
      {  name: 'EEE',  id: 101},
    {  name: 'DDD',  id: 102} ]
```

I tried to concatenate ,but it added to the last position.

Any help willbe appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method one

If you know that `json1` is already sorted by `id` values then you could iterate through the objects in `json2` and use the `.splice` method to insert them.

```js
var json1=
  [{  name: 'AAA', id: 100},
    {  name: 'BBB', id: 100 },
    {  name: 'CCC',  id: 101},
    {  name: 'DDD',  id: 102} ]
var json2=
 [ {  name: 'EEE',  id: 101}
    ]
var jsonCombined = json1.slice(); //make a copy of json1
for (let obj of json2) {
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonCombined.length; i++) {
        if (jsonCombined[i]['id'] == obj['id']) {
            jsonCombined.splice(i + 1, 0, obj);
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(jsonCombined);
```

#### Method two

On the other hand, if you do not know that `json1` is sorted then you can just combine the two json arrays and sort the objects based on their `id`s.

```js
var json1=
  [{  name: 'AAA', id: 100},
    {  name: 'BBB', id: 100 },
    {  name: 'CCC',  id: 101},
    {  name: 'DDD',  id: 102} ]
var json2=
 [ {  name: 'EEE',  id: 101}
    ]
var jsonCombined = json1.concat(json2).sort((a,b) => a['id'] > b['id'] ? 1 : -1);
console.log(jsonCombined);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var combinedjson = [...json1, ...json2].sort((a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1);
```